# Is there a more efficient way to have this C program print different things based on results of addition?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program which reads three integers, where if any two of those integers equal the remaining integer, it will print all integers within 1 and 10. If not, it will ask for three more integers and print the number of integers that are divisible by 6.
This is my program, but it looks long-winded. Is there a cleaner way to do it? Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x,y,z;
    
    printf("Enter three integers.\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    
    if(x + y == z){ 
        printf("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9");
    }
    else if(x+z == y){
        printf("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9");
    }
    else if(y+z == x){
        printf("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9");
    }
    else {
        int a, b, c, count;
        count = 0;
        printf("Type in three more integers.\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c); 
        if(a%6 == 0){
            count++;
        }
        if(b%6 == 0){
            count++;
        }
        if(c%6 == 0){
            count++;
        }
        printf("%d integers are divisible by 6.", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code works, but you're looking to improve it, it's best to try the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can use functions to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: You can use arrays and loop instead of repeating the same code on individual variables.

Comment: Combine the first three if conditions with '||', also with the sub if conditions

Comment: `if (x + y == z || x + z == y || y + z == x) { …print 1..9… } else { … }` —— and `printf("%d integers are divisible by 6\n", (c % 6 == 0) + (b % 6 == 0) + (a % 6 == 0));` — and do away with `count` and the conditionals.  You should check that the inputs were successful before using the results.  You should end printing with newlines.  It's not immediately obvious why you don't print `10` too, given the (loose) specification of "integers within 1 and 10".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Can put three if conditions on one using `||` operator. This tutorial can help. [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_logical_operators.htm)
2. If only wish to check divisible for 3 integers `(c % 6 == 0) + (b % 6 == 0) + (a % 6 == 0)` can help to get the count.
3. And reusing the same variables will help in optimizing memory.

Solution code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    printf("Enter three integers.\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    if(x + y == z || x+z == y || y+z == x)
    {
        printf("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Type in three more integers.\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
        printf("%d integers are divisible by 6\n", (x % 6 == 0) + (y % 6 == 0) + (z % 6 == 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: the return value of `scanf` is not checked. If i didn't successfully read all three ints, the variables are uninitialized and then you're dealing with undefined behavior.

Comment: So for point 2, (c % 6 == 0) will return a 1 if true and 0 if false?

Comment: Yes @not_castillo

Answer (score 2):

"*Is there a cleaner way to do it?*"
**Yes!** Write less code and reuse code and variables...

**EDIT:** removed *bad* code example and effected light "touch-ups"

```
void get3ints( char *prmpt, int *x, int *y, int *z ) {
    printf( "Enter three %sintegers.", prmpt );
    scanf( "%d %d %d", x, y, z ); // != 3 /* omitting check */
}

int main() {
    int x, y, z;

    get3ints( "", &x, &y, &z );
    if( (+x+y-z) * (+x-y+z) * (-x+y+z) ) {
        get3ints( "more ", &x, &y, &z );
        printf( "%d integers are divisible by 6.\n", !(x%6) + !(y%6) + !(z%6) );
    } else
        printf( "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

---

Without clarification of the objective, words like "efficient" (in the title) or "cleaner" (in the OP body) are subject to interpretation.

Below is code that fulfills the objective, built up of several discrete functions. One could argue that this is "cleaner" because each function cares little how its subordinate functions do their job; just that the job is done properly and the result returned is what is wanted.

*Many ways to skin a cat*

```
int t1( int x, int y, int z ) { return x+y==z || x==y+z || y==x+z; }
int t2( int x, int y, int z ) { return !(x%6) + !(y%6) + !(z%6); }

int get3ints( char *prmpt, int(*f)(int, int, int) ) {
    int x, y, z;
    printf( "Enter three %sintegers.", prmpt );
    scanf( "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z ); // != 3 /* omitting check */
    return f(x,y,z);
}

bool phase2() {
    printf( "%d integers are divisible by 6.\n", get3ints( "more ", t2 ) );
    return true;
}

bool phase1() {
    int rval;
    printf( &"\0 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\n"[rval = get3ints( "", t1 )] );
    return rval;
}

int main() {
    phase1() || phase2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neat to rewrite the sum.

Comment: @AllanWind Just a little bit bored... `:-)` Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: In the second rewrite, the order of evaluation in the second `printf()` is not defined, so it is not clear that `help()` will be called before the comparison/addition is done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. I've removed that code example (that came from a "bad day.") I was unaware the "order is not defined". My experience had always been 'R-to-L' for pushing parameters on the stack. Thank you for the correction. `:-)` (How would you feel if I ditched the braces, though, and exploited the comma to have the help() ahead of the printf() ... JK... JK!!!)

Comment: Using one comma operator instead of two braces would work correctly, but isn't a particularly great idea otherwise.  What you've written (in the revised answer) is essentially what I'd write — give or take the placement of the open braces.  (To a first approximation, I use [Allman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) style; you're using 1TBS.)

Comment: Unlike the conditionals the two multiplications might overflow.  I am much less worried with the additions.

Comment: @AllanWind You are right about o'flow. Then again, the user could enter INT_MAX-1 twice and INT_MIN+1 as the 3rd, and then the addition results are out of range... "To infinty and beyond!!!" `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is version that uses:

1. Function `input()` to reduce duplicate code of the prompt and reading data from user.
2. `scanf()` error handling
3. Early return for less branched code
4. Macro `SUM` to make variable part stand out, and derive the index of the right hand side to reduce chance of error.
5. Macro `MOD6` to make the variable part stand out.
6. Reuse array variable `a` just to make it a line shorter.  This is usually bad practice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input(const char *prompt, int *a) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if(scanf("%d %d %d", a, a + 1, a + 2) != 3) {
        printf("failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a[3];

    if(input("Enter three integers.\n", a))
        return 1;
    #define SUM(i, j) a[(i)] + a[(j)] == a[3 - (i) - (j)]
    if(SUM(0, 1) || SUM(0, 2) || SUM(1, 2)) {
        printf("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9");
        return 0;
    }
    #undef SUM

    if(input("Type in three more integers.\n", a))
        return 1;
    #define MOD6(i) !(a[(i)] % 6)
    printf("%d integers are divisible by 6.\n", 
        MOD6(0) + MOD6(1) + MOD6(2)
    );
    #undef MOD6
}
```

Comment: To me, having `input` return `1` for failure and `0` for success, while it mirrors `main`, reads wrong. It feels like this is saying: "if input succeeds, error and quit."

Comment: @Chris It's a fair comment.  There is one happy path (0) and many failures (!0). Reading it as "if input returns an error" and with enough of these it becomes the norm.  Reverting the logic in main seemed more ugly.  I did consider assign it to a variable with a goto done and return said variable.  goto usually earns me downvotes.

Comment: My two cents? (Who asked?) `input()` currently only fails when `scanf()` fails, and then it's a quick march out the door... "Out the **door**??" Hey! why not just go straight to the `exit(1)` (with <stdlib.h>, naturally) `input()` is then `void input()` **Do or die!!** `:-)`

Comment: That's too inflexible. It doesn't provide the option to handle an input failure by prompting again.

Comment: @Fe2OS3 I welcome any and all input.